# PHP exit makes my code work

Tags: php, codeigniter, exit

Can't quite believe I'm asking this question but here goes....

(Using PHP within Codeigniter)

I am integrating Barclays EPDQ into an e-commerce site for taking credit card payments. On successful payment EPDQ redirects back to the site passing query string parameters in the URL. I am looking for the orderID sent back from EPDQ, if its there I store a few things in the PHP session and redirect to the payment confirmation page. If the payment was unsuccessful the order ID won't be there and so I redirect to a payment failed method which shows a CI view file.

The condition for this check and session save routine is as follows:

```
$success = false;

if($_GET['orderID'])
{
    $_SESSION['payment']['order_id']  = $_GET['orderID'];
    $_SESSION['payment']['method']    = 'card';
    $_SESSION['payment']['ref']       = $_GET['PAYID'];
    $_SESSION['payment']['status']    = 'Completed';

    $success = true;
}
```

(please note the session is initialised and the payment array created prior to this code executing)

Pretty simple so far, right. The code for the directions then looks like this:

```
if(!$success)
{
    redirect('payment/card/fail');
}
else
{
    redirect('payment/confirmation');
}
```

The issue I am having is that this redirection doesn't work as I would expect. EPDQ reports successful payment and redirects back to our site as required. However when my script evaulates the GET parameters that it sends and goes to do the redirect it always uses the failed redirection............unless, and this is the bit that is really stumping me, I do this:

```
if(!$success)
{
    exit('Failed');
    redirect('payment/card/fail');
}
else
{
    redirect('payment/confirmation');
}
```

(note the added 'exit').

Once I include this exit the code executes as desired in all test cases and we start to see the payment success page. Removing the exit immediately reverts back to 100% tests failing.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening as I've not ever seen this before?

Comment: Ah..aa..aah.. LOL!  +1 for title!

Comment: can you show us the how controller..

Comment: can you post the code for `redirect()`

Comment: @Adelphia redirect is Codeigniter help function

Comment: please check your controller,If there is any blank space occure before "<?php" sometimes redirect does not work

Comment: Redirection is working in all cases and so it is not a whitespace issue (which we are all familiar with). The issue is that without the exit, and even though the session variables are being set, the success redirection is never called.

Comment: You should update your post with the raw code, not just the chunks that you suspect. Also, do you have any redirects anywhere else during this process (maybe in a model or something you forgot about)?

Comment: Maybe you miss an php exception when redirect() is called, check your php error config.

Comment: And the answer is - nothing to do with PHP. The reason this was happening was as a result of a setting within Barclays EPDQ which was sending out a response ahead of the main payment response. This meant my function was being hit twice, once without the GET params and once with. Putting in the exit meant that the failure redirection on the first hit wasn't executed and so the script was allowed to show the success. Removing this setting from EPDQ now means all conditions execute as required. +1 for lighta prompting me to go back to the logs. Thanks everyone. Sorry it wasn't really a PHP error.

Answer (score 1):

The only possible explanation is the case that $success is not updated and it is taking its preassigned value false. Check the value of $success by var_dump.

Comment: This was one of the first things I actually checked. The use of the $success var was in fact a later update I added in in response to this issue. If you look in the success condition I am setting some session variables; Regardless of the inclusion of the exit these variables are set when a successful payment is made

Answer (score 1):

The reason this was happening was as a result of a setting within Barclays EPDQ which was sending out a response ahead of the main payment response (this is a pre response repsonse allowing the site to be customised based on an incoming success or failure). This meant my function was being hit twice, once without the GET params on the first hit and once with them when the full payment response with params was returned. Putting in the exit meant that the failure redirection on the first hit wasn't executed and so the script was allowed to show the success condition. Removing/unsetting this pre-response from EPDQ now means all conditions execute as required.

In the end not really a PHP issue but worth noting in case anyone is working on integrating EPDQ and mistakenly sets this response within the admin interface of EPDQ.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, if the only way to reach *redirect('payment/confirmation')* is by adding a call to exit construct, I would assume redirection to failure route happens in all cases (even though the script is supposed to end successfully).